# How can I stop Ubuntu 12.04 from mounting Fedora 16's Swap Partition?

Tags: 12.04, swap

I recently installed Fedora and Ubuntu 12.04. Both have different Swap Partition. Fedora using its own Swap space. But Ubuntu using both two swap partitions. I want to stop that. I want Ubuntu 12 to use its own Swap Partition.

- `sda9` - Ubuntu (/)
- `sda11` - Swap (4.9 GB)
- `sda10` - Fedora (/)
- `sda12` - Swap (4.9 GB)

All are logical partitions.

Comment: Anyone, please explain how I can or where I can add the "noauto" command in the "fstab" file?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you get rid of the extra swap line in `/etc/fstab`.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the `noauto` option in `/etc/fstab` for your Ubuntu system's `sda10` partition.

Answer (score 0):

The swap space is set in `/etc/fstab`. In your case you probably want Ubuntu to use `sda11` partition, so you should remove the line in fstab that contains the `/dev/sda12` partition.