# Problems with partitions installing net verison Ubuntu alongside Win 7 Home Prem

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows-7

I'm stuck installing Ubuntu 14.04 with the partition part of the install.
I am downloading and using the net install since I can't burn DVDs, so I just downloaded the mini.iso and burned it to disc and restarted.

I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 along a Windows 7 Home Premium, and I have a 250GB hard drive and have done the partition part, but I get stuck and can't get it to work right. It's listed now on the computer as follows.

- (windows) #1 - Primary 78.8 GB - B -K Ntfs  /
- (Ubuntu) #5 logical 170.3 GB k ext41 /
- (swap) #6 logical 1.0GB k swap swap

I don't know how to get it to work right with mounting and it's not letting me mount both #1 and #5 partitions as / . I marked #1 as Bootable and still can't get through and would appreciate any help on how to proceed and keep my Windows 7, and add Ubuntu side by side Thanks.

Also, I don't have the original Win 7 Home Premium restore disks of any kind, and any help would be appreciated.

John Nicks

Comment: Also, if I go ahead and choose the do not mount option, and countine with the install, can I go back after the install of Ubuntu and GRUB boot loader and mount it back to where I can get both Windows 7 and Ubuntu running side by side?

Answer (score 0):

Ordinarily, each filesystem partition that you want to access in Linux has a *unique* mount point; you can't simultaneously mount two partitions at root (`/`). Furthermore, you can't use an NTFS volume as your Linux root (`/`) filesystem. If you want to access your Windows partition from Linux, you must give it some other mount point, such as `/mnt/windows`. Because Windows contains no special system files from Linux's perspective, there's no need to give it any privileged mount point.

Comment: I'm not trying to install it on the same partition. When I go in as a mount point it has the option for /dos /windows and other mount point or do not use use.  I have tried with /dos, /windows, and used just / as a custom mount point but I will try that. I don't want to lose any data in the process, and I am not planning on sharing files between Ubuntu and Win 7, just leaving Partition 1 alone and Ubuntu as partition #5, and swap #6.

Comment: Just to confirm Rod, I will be able to continue the install and everything will be fine with my Win 7 if I type in /mnt/windows in the custom mount point for partition #1.

Comment: I just tried and it said that the mount #1 to /mnt/windows failed. Now what?

Comment: Here is an image to I am talking about is here [link]( http://jlnicks.com/linux/linuxpart01.JPG )

Comment: If you don't want to access the Windows partition from Linux, then do not assign the Windows partition a mount point. This is safer than mounting it unnecessarily, since leaving it unmounted will eliminate the risk of accidentally trashing your Windows files from Linux. That said, you may need to take steps *after* installing Ubuntu to keep the Windows volume from auto-mounting, as described [here.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/165702/how-can-i-prevent-ubuntu-from-mounting-particular-partitions-deivices)